# Проблема с количеством товаров в корзине при занесении её в local storage

Tags: javascript

написал функцию которая принимает id нового товара и заносит её в корзину которая лежит в
local srorage. Когда кликаешь по одному товару то всё работает как нужно, увеличивается counter и все ок. НО когда добавляешь ещё один товар то вместе с увеличение count добавляется ещё один товар. Не могу понять с чем связано уже голову сломал. Код

```js
// Получаем данные из LocalStorage
function getCartData() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
}
// Записываем данные в LocalStorage
function setCartData(o) {
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(o));
  
}


// Добавляем товар в корзину
function addItemToBag(newItem) {

    var cartData = getCartData() || []; // получаем данные корзины или создаём новый объект, если данных еще нет
  
      if(cartData.length==0){ // если в массиве ничего не лежит создаем нулевой элемент
         cartData.push({
                    id: newItem,
                    count: 1
                });
         }else{
    
          for (let i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) { //цикл в котором проверяем не лежит ли уже товар с таким id корзине
            
            if (cartData[i].id === newItem) { // если лежит то увеличиваем count
              
                   cartData[i].count+=1;
            } else { //если нет то добавляем новый
               
                cartData.push({
                    id: newItem,
                    count: 1
                });
            }
        }
         }

    setCartData(cartData)  // Обновляем данные в LocalStorage
}
```

Скрин что выводит в local storage
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var cartData = getCartData() || [];
var oldItem = null;

for (let i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
  if (cartData[i].id === newItem) {
    oldItem = cartData[i];
    break;
  }
}

if (oldItem) {
  oldItem.count = oldItem.count + 1;
} else {
  cartData.push({
    id: newItem,
    count: 1
  });
}

setCartData(cartData);
```

Comment: А ошибка-то в чём заключалась?